# Учебное задание на И и ИЛИ

Tags: c

Вывести результат логических действий И и ИЛИ.
Пример ввода:

> 0 1

Пример вывода:

> 0 AND 1 is 0 0 OR 1 is 1

Вот так написал. Проблема в восьмой строчке, там где if

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int n, m;

  scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);

  if ( n && m && n || m )
  {
    printf("n AND m is %d\n", n);
    printf("n OR m is %d\n", m);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мы видим явное непонимание принципов работы операторов в Си. Во-первых, условная конструкция if лишняя. Во-вторых, Вам никто не мешает сохранить результат выполнения логичесеих операторов в переменную. Например, a = n && m. Затем выведиье значения переменных на экран. За сим все.

Comment: Если так, то не выводит:

    a = n && m;
    b = n || m;
    if ( a && b ) {
        printf("n AND m is %d\n", n);
        printf("n OR m is %d\n", m);
    }

Comment: 0 и 1 - это не просто числа, а возврат операций И и ИЛИ

Comment: Без разницы. Примерный правильный код:
<code>a = n && m;
b = n || m;
printf ("%d AND %d is %d\n", n, m, a);
printf ("%d OR %d is %d\n", n, m, b);</code>

Comment: Спасибо разобрался!)